# Is there a machine independent compiler?

Tags: java, compiler-construction

I know java generates bytecode but the JVM needs to interpret it everytime during runtime.

Does a compiler exist that generates machine independent code, lets say for C.
Then at a target machine this is permanently converted to its local machine code once rather than converting for each run?

Does this solve why many developers develop for windows but no linux?

Comment: You actually don't want that. Java could do that, but it's not a good idea. The JVM can compile code not only for the system it's on but also the situation in which it's running. The way the bytecode is JITed today will not necissarily be the same as the way it is JITed tomorrow. Because of this (after warm up) java can sometimes outperform C++

Comment: It's fairly common to have a machine-independent "front-end", and then have the "back-end" do the conversion from a stack-based or quad-based notation to the target machine instructions.  A machine-independent optimizer can be stuck between the two.

Comment: @RichardTingle - The ability of JITCed Java to run faster than statically compiled code is exactly because it's not statically compiled.  Has nothing to do with machine-independence.  (There are, in fact JITCs that are constructed the way I describe above.)

Comment: @HotLicks Indeed, the point is that compiling once and then using that over and over isn't actually as awesome an idea as people think (even though it sounds like it would be). Machine independance is just an added bonus

Comment: @RichardTingle - Probably because Java is the only current architecture for doing it.  Lots of developers would like to be able ship compiled apps that can target different architectures, but there's no scheme other than Java for doing so.  Used to be the old P-code scheme, but that got buried under Borland in the early days of the PC.

Comment: (The problem with Windows vs Linux is as much a problem of different OS architectures as anything, and hence different I/O calls, etc.)

Comment: @HotLicks That's why the Java library only offers the greatest common functionality when it comes to IO and System things. It neither fully supports WIndows, nor UNIX nor anything else. But the intersection is big enough to write useful programs.

Comment: @RichardTingle See my answer mentioning ART for Android. So after all, it is a good idea, is it?

Comment: @lbalazscs I have heard of those. They can give better start up performance but worse long term performance. So it's a trade off

Comment: @RichardTingle Then at least for non-server apps it would be a good idea... :) But why do you think that the optimal machine code generated today (on a given machine) will not be optimal tomorrow? Can you give sources or explain?

Comment: @lbalazscs Of course if its running in exactly the same way you would expect performance to be identical. It's when the same code (especially a library) is run differently in different situations. To get the best performance from fully compiled code (such as C++) you can do something called [Profile-guided_optimization](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Profile-guided_optimization) in which how the program is going to be used is fed into the complilation process to get the best performance for the particular way you are going to use the program, java does something like this "on the fly"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's certainly possible, and [interpreters exist](https://www.google.com/search?q=C+interpreter) for C and C++. However, projects using these languages will often use platform-specific code (like the Windows APIs) which stops them from being portable. Interpreted languages generally supply platform-independent core libraries.

Modern compilers – like Clang, LLVM and GCC – all compile your source code to an intermediate language. This means that the same code-level optimizations can be applied to any language that the compiler can convert, and it also enables tools like [Emscripten](https://github.com/kripken/emscripten) which can effectively compile C to JavaScript! I believe it was used for the recent [JavaScript Unreal Engine demo](http://www.unrealengine.com/html5/).

Answer (score 2):

Not really, but some stuff comes close.

C is regarded as low level as possible while being portable by some. (This, of course, excludes all APIs). The GHC Haskell compiler uses internally a very c-like language in that regard c--, that might be very close to the machine in depended code you are looking for.

Most modern compilers do have such intermediate Code, for example LLVM. There is even a assembler like (so even more low leven than C) for that. But note that LLVM intermediate code is not portable, as for example the pointer size has to be known at compile time. (all the sizeofs in C will fixed at this time)

But there is a IMO more simple solution: Compile the code for any platform, and if you are on a different platform you a dynamic recompiler like QEMU. That still does negatively impact performance.

Comment: IBM mainframes do this though. Code (e.g. C) is compiled to an intermediate language, and translated to machine code when installed. They made pointer types used for the intermediate language 128 bits back in the 16 and 32 bit days (these get translated to the native pointer size) - which will be future proof for quite a while still.

Answer (score 0):

A Java example: Android 4.4 introduced a new experimental runtime virtual machine, ART (Android Runtime).

> > ART straddles an interesting mid-ground between compiled and interpreted code, called ahead-of-time (AOT) compilation. Currently with Android apps, they are interpreted at runtime (using the JIT), every time you open them up. This is slow. (iOS apps, by comparison, are compiled native code, which is much faster.) With ART enabled, each Android app is compiled to native code when you install it. Then, when it’s time to run the app, it performs with all the alacrity of a native app.

[Source](http://www.extremetech.com/computing/170677-android-art-google-finally-moves-to-replace-dalvik-to-boost-performance-and-battery-life)

Comment: Good to know there is some progress in that direction. Java was always slow

Comment: @user3041058 Java was usually slower than optimized C/C++, but faster than most other languages. Java performance was optimized for long-running apps such as servers. For Android apps startup time and initial performance is important, therefore it is good to see progress in that direction.